# How do I interpret my hypothesis in question given my data analysis results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have little statistics background and I am struggling to interpret these results in a data analysis.

I wanted to test: 'Body image dissatisfaction is more likely to develop in female adolescents than in male adolescents.' I have attached a picture of my Crosstabs. My p-value was found to be (<0.001) and my Cramer's v to be (0.085). So, I am able to reject the null. However, the data shows little to no association and my Cramer's indicates a weak relationship. How do I go about this data analysis? I'm not sure how to properly interpret this.

```
Table: Body Image by Gender

                       Gender
Body Image           Male    Female

Too thin              14%      10%
About the right size  61%      59%
Too fat               25%      31%

Total                100%     100%
N                    6406     6056
```

Comment: Better to present your table as plain text; people can read it into packages and people with impaired vision can use screen readers to understand what it contains. Hypothesis tests *don't* look for substantive effects they look for any effect distinguishable from noise and in large samples like these, they will find them even if they are trivial in size (many posts on site discuss this). Your hesitation with simply rejecting the null at a large sample size suggests that standard homogeneity of proportions test was not the right tool to answer your real question of interest *at any sample size*

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was told I had to use the standard homogeneity of proportions test (Pearson Chi-square) to obtain a p-value, unfortunately. I'm not sure how to go about it given that I have to use this tool.

Comment: My first guess would be that you are thinking too complicated; this looks like a straightforward hypothesis test. You calculate the variance of your relative fractions (binomial, poissonian, gaussian or whatever else seems to fit). And compare if there is a "significant difference" between the two categories you compare. You have to decide what you define as "significant", e.g. "outside 95%" -- or roughly two standard deviations away.

Answer (score 2):

The test itself is easy to interpret; you reject the null hypothesis of homogeneity of proportions. The data indicate that the population proportions differ since a test statistic at least as large would be very unusual if the null were true.

The very small effect size is also relatively easy to interpret -- the proportions differ by only quite small amounts; it's just that with such a large sample size the test can detect considerably smaller differences still.

[Be very careful that you don't carry a chi-squared test on percentages, but on the counts (unless the formulas have been specifically adjusted to deal with a table in such a form, along with the N row). In addition be very careful not to use these rounded percentages in your calculations; when the standard errors are less than 1%, rounding to the nearest percent can give rounding error of more than one standard error!]